# How to compare only Date without Time in DateTime types?

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework

Is there a way to compare two `DateTime` variables but to disregard the Time part.

The app stores items in the DB and adds a published date. I want to keep the exact time but still be able to pull by the date itself.

I want to compare `12/3/89 12:43:34` and `12/3/89 11:22:12` and have it disregard the actual time of day so both of these are considered the same.

I guess I can set all the times of day to `00:00:00` before I compare but I actually do want to know the time of day I just also want to be able to compare by date only.

I found some code that has the same issue and they compare the year, month and day separately. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 696, accepted):

try using the `Date` property on the `DateTime` Object...

```
if(dtOne.Date == dtTwo.Date)
    ....
```

Comment: If you end up here sometime after early 2017 looking for a way to compare dates in an Entity Framework environment like I did check out the answer below by Alejandro and the comment by wasatchWizard.

Comment: If you end up here sometime after mid 2018 looking for a way to read another extremely helpful comment like the one above, you're out of luck.

Comment: This is absolutely NOT the correct answer. The OP specifically said Linq to SQL and datetime.date is NOT allowed in linq expressions.

Comment: @Mr.Ott 2021 here. Jan 20, USA (inauguration day) 4,367 Covid-19 deaths. But yeah good tip. For my purposes of filtering by date range, I had an issue because DateTime.Today uses time of 00:00:00 so I just used DateTime.Today.AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59).AddSeconds(59) instead.

Comment: At first I thought this worked but it doesn't. When you have different "time of days" in your datetime object this solution does not work

Comment: If you end up here sometimes after late 2021 looking for confirmation on this answer. It does work.

Comment: The comment on MSDN for the 'Date' property says "A new object with the same date as this instance, and the time value set to 12:00:00 midnight (00:00:00)." And the operator for '==' is implemented like this: (DateTime d1, DateTime d2) => d1.InternalTicks == d2.InternalTicks. Thats is why the answer seems perfectly okay to me.

Answer (score 68):

For a true comparison, you can use:

```
dateTime1.Date.CompareTo(dateTime2.Date);
```

Comment: doesn't "==" return the results from CompareTo internally?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "true comparison"?

Comment: SnOrfus: Not always.  Many implementations return a.CompareTo(b)==0 for ==, but that's up to the implementation.  I haven't checked DateTime's internal implemetnation of equality.

Comment: Randolpho:  Using == will give you equality, so whether the two dates are the same or different.  CompareTo will ~compare~ them, ie: give you a way in one pass to tell if date1>date2, date1<date2, or date1==date2.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Can't you just use (dateTime1.Date < dateTime1.Date)?

Comment: @David Not if you want a comparison - a comparison (in .NET terms) will return -1/0/1 depending on the values.

Comment: But who wants `-1`, `0` and `1`, really? They are just magical numbers representing "less", "equal" and "greater". And you will have to "compare" the resulting integer to something afterwards because there are three possible values. I must agree with @David that it is much more natural to use `dateTime1.Date < dateTime1.Date`, and similarly with `<=`, `>` and `>=`, in most applications.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen If you're using this in anything that sorts or takes a comaprison, then you want it - otherwise, you typically just want the operators.

Comment: Just looked this up. `DateTime`s `==` compares the number of `Ticks` of the two objects (or rather `structs`) so `CompareTo` would seem unnecessary here. [see msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.op_equality(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_1)

Comment: @BjörnAliGöransson That's equality, not comparison... comparison returns -1/0/1, not true/false.

Comment: @ReedCopsey I strongly believe that the OP is using "comparison" in the sense of "equality comparison" (just looked it up, the word is actually in the [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183752.aspx))

Comment: This wont work as it still compares the time value. See TruncateTime.

Answer (score 67):

This is how I do this in order to work with LINQ.

```
DateTime date_time_to_compare = DateTime.Now;
//Compare only date parts
context.YourObject.FirstOrDefault(r =>
                EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(r.date) == EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(date_to_compare));
```

If you only use `dtOne.Date == dtTwo.Date` it wont work with LINQ (Error: The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities)

Comment: This works great with LINQ to Entities. However, `EntityFunctions` has been deprecated in .NET 4.5.2. Use this instead: `DbFunctions.TruncateTime`. It appears to be the identical method, just moved..

Comment: According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40758784/dbfunctions-truncatetime-linq-equivalent-in-ef-core) this is no longer needed in EF Core

Answer (score 35):

If you're using Entity Framework < v6.0, then use `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime`
If you're using Entity Framework >= v6.0, then use `DbFunctions.TruncateTime`

Use either (based on your EF version) around any `DateTime` class property you want to use inside your Linq query

Example

```
var list = db.Cars.Where(c=> DbFunctions.TruncateTime(c.CreatedDate) 
                                       >= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.UtcNow));
```

Comment: Just a reminder here: As long as it is Linq to Entity.

Comment: This should be the correct answer (as of 2019). EntityFunctions is depreciated and you're not allowed to use datetime.date in a lambda expression (for whatever reason - I mean seriously... why haven't they fixed this?!).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Either that or possibly reset time on either side of the DateTime comparison. e.g. `LHS <= RHS` where `LHS` is `startDateTime.Date`  **(00:00 AM)** and `RHS` is `endDateTime.Date.AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59).AddSeconds(59)` **(23:59:59 PM)**

Answer (score 12):

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Now.Date;
DateTime dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox4.Text.Trim()).Date;
if (dt1 >= dt2)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Valid Date");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Date... Please Give Correct Date....");
}
```

Answer (score 11):

```
DateTime? NextChoiceDate = new DateTime();
DateTIme? NextSwitchDate = new DateTime();
if(NextChoiceDate.Value.Date == NextSwitchDate.Value.Date)
{
Console.WriteLine("Equal");
}
```

You can use this if you are using nullable DateFields.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question how to do it in Entity Framework.

Comment: The question mentions DateTime but nothing about EF, so this answer is perfectly valid

Answer (score 3):

```
DateTime dt1=DateTime.ParseExact(date1,"dd-MM-yyyy",null);
DateTime dt2=DateTime.ParseExact(date2,"dd-MM-yyyy",null);

int cmp=dt1.CompareTo(dt2);

   if(cmp>0) {
       // date1 is greater means date1 is comes after date2
   } else if(cmp<0) {
       // date2 is greater means date1 is comes after date1
   } else {
       // date1 is same as date2
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime econvertedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(end_date);
DateTime sconvertedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(start_date);

TimeSpan age = econvertedDate.Subtract(sconvertedDate);
Int32 diff = Convert.ToInt32(age.TotalDays);
```

The diff value represents the number of days for the age.  If the value is negative the start date falls after the end date.  This is a good check.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
if(dtOne.Year == dtTwo.Year && dtOne.Month == dtTwo.Month && dtOne.Day == dtTwo.Day)
  ....
```

Answer (score 2):

In **.NET 5**:

To compare date without time you must use `EF.Functions.DateDiffDay()` otherwise you will be comparing in code and this means you are probably pulling way more data from the DB than you need to.

```
.Where(x => EF.Functions.DateDiffDay(x.ReceiptDate, value) == 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your join or where clause, use the `Date` property of the column. Behind the scenes, this executes a `CONVERT(DATE, <expression>)` operation. This should allow you to compare dates without the time.

Answer (score -19):

```
        int o1 = date1.IndexOf("-");
        int o2 = date1.IndexOf("-",o1 + 1);
        string str11 = date1.Substring(0,o1);
        string str12 = date1.Substring(o1 + 1, o2 - o1 - 1);
        string str13 = date1.Substring(o2 + 1);

        int o21 = date2.IndexOf("-");
        int o22 = date2.IndexOf("-", o1 + 1);
        string str21 = date2.Substring(0, o1);
        string str22 = date2.Substring(o1 + 1, o2 - o1 - 1);
        string str23 = date2.Substring(o2 + 1);

        if (Convert.ToInt32(str11) > Convert.ToInt32(str21))
        {
        }
        else if (Convert.ToInt32(str12) > Convert.ToInt32(str22))
        {
        }
        else if (Convert.ToInt32(str12) == Convert.ToInt32(str22) && Convert.ToInt32(str13) > Convert.ToInt32(str23))
        {
        }
```

Comment: -1: Why not just parse to DateTime and use @Quintin Robinson's method? This is code I would expect to see on the The Daily WTF.

Comment: No need to create this much variables as it increase response time for such a easy task.