# EF5 + Using the 'LIKE' operator inside a Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, lambda

In my Entity (Sale) has a type of `DateTime` column `Date`.

I used following lambda expression to get the latest `TrNo` from that table. But always it gives me `Null`. Because it also compares the `Time` part of the column. Actually I wanted to compare the `Date` part of the column.

```
db.Sales.OrderByDescending(O => O.Date).Where(O => O.Date == DateTime.Now ).Select(O => O.TrNo).FirstOrDefault();
```

Please help me to get the build the right code. (My db is MySQL)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If `O.Date` is a Date, simply compare it against `DateTime.Now.Date`, since `DateTime.Now` will return both the Date & Time. If `O.Date` is actually a `DateTime`, simply do the same, `O.Date.Date == DateTime.Now.Date`.

Comment: I'm not sure that EF can transform this expression into sql code.

Comment: Thanks but it throws,

`The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.`

Comment: Yea. It looks like you are correct. I would recommend that the OP takes a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478215/how-to-compare-only-date-components-from-datetime-in-ef

Comment: Just move your DateTime value to separate variable, and then use it inside LINQ query

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to test the date portion of the datetime try this.

```
db.Sales.OrderByDescending(O => O.Date).Where(O => O.Date == DateTime.Now.Date ).Select(O => O.TrNo).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: DateTime.Now.Date is DateTime with time 00:00.000, so your query will return null.