# Dynamically select column name using Linq to Entities (EF6)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

I want to encapsulate common scenarios when using EF6.
Here's an example:

```
   public class StringRequest : DbRequestProperty
   {
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public bool? ExactMatch { get; set; }

      protected override bool IsValid()
      {
         return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name);
      }

      private bool RequestExactMatch()
      {
         return ExactMatch.HasValue && ExactMatch.Value;
      }

      protected override IQueryable<T> Execute<T>(IQueryable<T> original, string propertyName)
      {
         return RequestExactMatch()
            ? original.Where(o => GetProperty<string>(o, propertyName) == Name)
            : original.Where(o => GetProperty<string>(o, propertyName).Contains(Name));
      }
   }
```

But GetProperty can't be converted to a query.
So I'm thinking on selecting dynamically the column using "propertyName".

```
  protected override IQueryable<T> Execute<T>(IQueryable<T> original, string propertyName)
  {
     return RequestExactMatch()
        ? original.Where(o => GetColumnByName<string>(propertyName) == Name)
        : original.Where(o => GetColumnByName<string>(propertyName).Contains(Name));
  }
```

Is this possible?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can dynamically create a `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` using the [Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) class like this:

```
protected override IQueryable<T> Execute<T>(IQueryable<T> original, string propertyName)
{
   var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
   var property = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, propertyName);
   var constant = Expression.Constant(Name);

   Expression predicate;
   if(RequestExactMatch())  
   {     
      predicate = Expression.Equal(property, constant);    
   }
   else 
   {
      predicate = Expression.Call(property, "Contains", null, constant);    
   }

   var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(predicate, parameter);

   return original.Where(lambda);
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir. It worked perfectly. You helped me refactor tons of repeated code.

Comment: What about dates. Is there a way to truncate the time part on the database part so I end up comparing only dates? I've tried using Convert and Cast but I get an exception saying that those functions don't exist on System.Date

Comment: @Chorinator - I believe there is a way, but ask another question

Comment: I've found a way to do it, based on this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/1759993/261549