# How to compare date in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I want to compare date, datetime field in Entity Framework. In my database, I have a column `StartTime` as `date` or `smalldatetime`. Ok, I use this case

```
var list = db.tmpListAction.Where(e => e.StartTime.ToString() == "2017-12-15").ToList();
```

It's not working. It returns `null` although I have data in table.

Comment: `e.StartTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare only date components from DateTime in EF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478215/how-to-compare-only-date-components-from-datetime-in-ef)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why bother converting to a string again?? That most likely breaks your code, since the `.ToString()` isn't guaranteed to return the data representation you're expecting.

Just leave the date as a date and compare like this:

```
DateTime desiredDate = new DateTime(2017, 12, 15);
var list = db.tmpListAction.Where(e => e.StartTime == desiredDate).ToList();
```

Comment: Dear @marc_s , as you see in my case, i want to compare this as a string, so i try to use ```"2017-12-15"``` , I confused that i like use string.

Comment: @Brian Crist, why are you insistent about comparing dates as string ? It is not proper way.