# Oracle Entity Framework Blazor WASM - InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, api, blazor, webassembly

Using Visual Studio 2022 Net6 to build a view only app of an existing database.  I used Oracle Entity Framework to scaffold the model and context.  Mostly it's fine, but I have come across this error that I cannot pin down.  When I call the API to get my order objects, I get the following error:

```
InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetByte(int i)
lambda_method12(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , SingleQueryResultCoordinator )
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable<T>+AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource> source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource> source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
OracleWCON_V2.Server.Controllers.OrdersController.Get() in OrdersController.cs
+
            return await _context.Orders.Where(o => o.SoDeliveryDate.Date >= DateTime.Now.Date).ToListAsync();
lambda_method5(Closure , object )
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor+AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[] arguments)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask<IActionResult> actionResultValueTask)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Please not that this has nothing to do with the date comparison in the controller, that is just there to restrict the number of records returned.  I get the same result if I query for just one record (that fits the bill for whatever column is failing).  Even knowing the data from a failing column, I have been unable to get to the bottom of the issue.

Here is the Model object:

```
using OracleWCON_V2.RODataAccess.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

#nullable disable

namespace OracleWCON_V2.RODataAccess.Context
{
    public partial class Order
    {
        public decimal SoIaInvoiceAccount { get; set; }
        public decimal OrderId { get; set; }
        public decimal? SoSioOrderGroup { get; set; }
        public string SoTown { get; set; }
        public string SoAddress1 { get; set; }
        public string SoAddress2 { get; set; }
        public string SoAddress3 { get; set; }
        public string SoCustOrderNo { get; set; }
        public decimal? SoCustQuoteNo { get; set; }
        public DateTime SoDeliveryDate { get; set; }
        public string SoEoShortName { get; set; }
        public string SoFocAuthorisation { get; set; }
        public decimal? SoLatNumber { get; set; }
        public decimal? SoMileageAdj { get; set; }
        public decimal? SoOrigInvoiceAccount { get; set; }
        public decimal? SoOurOrderNo { get; set; }
        public string? SoPrintBreak { get; set; }
        public string? SoPurchRefNo { get; set; }
        public decimal? SoQuoNumber { get; set; }
        public string SoSplInfo { get; set; }
        public string SoToBeLinked { get; set; }
        public decimal? SoPlSupplierAccNo { get; set; }
        public string SoType { get; set; }
        public string SoTrainDetails { get; set; }
        public string SoQpName { get; set; }
        public int? SoRcNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime? SoPurchInvDate { get; set; }
        public int? SoFyPurchInvNo { get; set; }
        public string SoSalesRecharge { get; set; }
        public DateTime? SoWhenPlaced { get; set; }
        public int? SoEmpTakenBy { get; set; }
        public string SoPlacedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime? SoWhenLastCommitted { get; set; }
        public int? SoLastCommittedBy { get; set; }
        public byte? SoReadbackSeconds { get; set; }
        public string SoTbc { get; set; }
        public string SoWhyTbc { get; set; }
        public DateTime? SoWhenLinked { get; set; }
        public int? SoEmpLinkedBy { get; set; }
        public string SoAddress4 { get; set; }
        public string SoMultiDrop { get; set; }
        public string SoExworks { get; set; }
        public string SoWaitingForCash { get; set; }
        public string SoAwaitingCreditApproval { get; set; }
        public int? SoIoReference { get; set; }
        public string SoOrderOffice { get; set; }
        public string SoSitePhone { get; set; }
        public string SoCancelled { get; set; }
        public int? SoSoBasedOn { get; set; }
        public string SoTorrExwTown { get; set; }
        public string SoTorrExwDestination { get; set; }
        public string SoOutOfHours { get; set; }
        public decimal? SoTotalDayworkHours { get; set; }
        public string SoJobToFinish { get; set; }
        public string SoIncomingJourney { get; set; }
        public string SoCanTakeToday { get; set; }
        public byte? SoRecycleSource { get; set; }
        public string SoLccApplies { get; set; }
        public DateTime? SoWhenLastChecked { get; set; }
        public int? SoLastCheckedBy { get; set; }
        public string SoOwContract { get; set; }
        public string SoApproved { get; set; }
        public DateTime? SoDateApproved { get; set; }
        public string SoReceived { get; set; }
        public DateTime? SoDateReceived { get; set; }
        public string SoQuery { get; set; }
        public byte? SoApprovedBy { get; set; }
        public string SoSiteContact { get; set; }
        public string SoPlacedByPhone { get; set; }
        public string SoOrdNotificationCt1 { get; set; }
        public string SoOrdNotificationCt2 { get; set; }
        public string SoDespNotificationCt1 { get; set; }
        public string SoDespNotificationCt2 { get; set; }
        public decimal? SoCt1CtId { get; set; }
        public decimal? SoCt2CtId { get; set; }
        public string SoPlacedByPhone2 { get; set; }
        public string SoSitePhone2 { get; set; }
        public string SoPlanned { get; set; }
        public string SoPostcode1 { get; set; }
        public string SoPostcode2 { get; set; }
        public decimal? SoSiteLat { get; set; }
        public decimal? SoSiteLong { get; set; }
        public string SoTmsTntLink { get; set; }
        public string SoCancelledContact { get; set; }
        public decimal? SoCt3CtId { get; set; }
        public string SoDelInstructions { get; set; }
        public string SoCashCustAcc { get; set; }
        public decimal? SoMovedIntOrderRef { get; set; }
        public decimal? SoMovedOurRef { get; set; }
        public DateTime? SoMovedTo { get; set; }

    }
}
```

And here is the controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using OracleWCON_V2.RODataAccess.Context;
using OracleWCON_V2.RODataAccess.Models;

namespace OracleWCON_V2.Server.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class OrdersController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly OrderContext _context;

        public OrdersController(OrderContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/<Orders>
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Order>> Get()
        {
            return await _context.Orders.Where(o => o.SoDeliveryDate.Date >= DateTime.Now.Date).ToListAsync();
            //return await _context.Orders.Include(e => e.OrderLines).ToListAsync();
        }

        // GET api/<Orders>/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Order>> GetOneOrderAsync(int id)
        {
            return await _context.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderId == id).ToListAsync();
        }

        //GET api/<Orders>/cust/1
        [HttpGet("cust/{id}")]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Order>> GetCustomerOrders(int id)
        {
            return await _context.Orders.Where(o => o.SoIaInvoiceAccount == id).ToListAsync();
        }

        // POST api/<Orders>
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/<Orders>/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/<Orders>/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the context:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using OracleWCON_V2.RODataAccess.Models;

#nullable disable

namespace OracleWCON_V2.RODataAccess.Context
{
    public partial class OrderContext : DbContext
    {
        public OrderContext()
        {
        }

        public OrderContext(DbContextOptions<OrderContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                String connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["wcon_ro"].ConnectionString;
                optionsBuilder.UseOracle(connStr);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {


            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("WCON_RO");

            modelBuilder.Entity<OrderLine>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => new { e.OrderId, e.OlLineNo })
                    .HasName("OL_PK");

                entity.ToTable("INV_ORDER_LINES", "LIVE");

                entity.Property(e => e.OrderId)
                    .HasColumnType("NUMBER(22)")
                    .HasColumnName("OL_SO_INT_ORDER_REF");

                entity.Property(e => e.OlLineNo)
                    .HasColumnType("NUMBER(22)")
                    .HasColumnName("OL_LINE_NO");

                entity.Property(e => e.OlAppReference)
                    .HasPrecision(6)
                    .HasColumnName("OL_APP_REFERENCE");

                entity.Property(e => e.OlBestEndeavours)
                    .HasMaxLength(1)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("OL_BEST_ENDEAVOURS");

                entity.Property(e => e.OlCanTakeMore)
                    .HasMaxLength(1)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("OL_CAN_TAKE_MORE");

                entity.Property(e => e.OlCashSaleUnitPrice)
                    .HasColumnType("NUMBER(6,2)")
                    .HasColumnName("OL_CASH_SALE_UNIT_PRICE");

                entity.Property(e => e.OlDeliveryRateType)
                    .HasMaxLength(2)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("OL_DELIVERY_RATE_TYPE");

                entity.Property(e => e.OlDepotRequested)
                    .HasPrecision(6)
                    .HasColumnName("OL_DEPOT_REQUESTED");

                entity.Property(e => e.OlEmpBeOverrider)
                    .HasPrecision(6)
                    .HasColumnName("OL_EMP_BE_OVERRIDER");

                entity.Property(e => e.OlEmpLastCommittedBy)
                    .HasPrecision(6)
                    .HasColumnName("OL_EMP_LAST_COMMITTED_BY");

                entity.Property(e => e.OlLastCommitted)
                    .HasColumnType("DATE")
                    .HasColumnName("OL_LAST_COMMITTED");

                entity.Property(e => e.OlLorriesOnTurnaround)
                    .HasPrecision(3)
                    .HasColumnName("OL_LORRIES_ON_TURNAROUND");

                entity.Property(e => e.OlMinsBetweenLoads)
                    .HasPrecision(4)
                    .HasColumnName("OL_MINS_BETWEEN_LOADS");

                entity.Property(e => e.OlNotes)
                    .HasMaxLength(60)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("OL_NOTES");

                entity.Property(e => e.OlOlLineDependantOn)
                    .HasPrecision(8)
                    .HasColumnName("OL_OL_LINE_DEPENDANT_ON");

                entity.Property(e => e.OlOoh)
                    .HasMaxLength(1)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("OL_OOH");

                entity.Property(e => e.OlPermissionToMix)
                    .HasMaxLength(1)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("OL_PERMISSION_TO_MIX");

                entity.Property(e => e.OlPrefPlant)
                    .HasMaxLength(3)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("OL_PREF_PLANT");

                entity.Property(e => e.OlPrice)
                    .HasColumnType("NUMBER(22,2)")
                    .HasColumnName("OL_PRICE");

                entity.Property(e => e.OlProductCode)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(6)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("OL_PRODUCT_CODE");

                entity.Property(e => e.OlProductDesc)
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("OL_PRODUCT_DESC");

                entity.Property(e => e.OlQuantity)
                    .HasColumnType("NUMBER(22,2)")
                    .HasColumnName("OL_QUANTITY");

                entity.Property(e => e.OlQuantityBeforeStop)
                    .HasColumnType("NUMBER(22,2)")
                    .HasColumnName("OL_QUANTITY_BEFORE_STOP");

                entity.Property(e => e.OlRequestedBy)
                    .HasMaxLength(30)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("OL_REQUESTED_BY");

                entity.Property(e => e.OlResumptionOfLine)
                    .HasColumnType("NUMBER(22)")
                    .HasColumnName("OL_RESUMPTION_OF_LINE");

                entity.Property(e => e.OlSplHaulInd)
                    .HasMaxLength(1)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("OL_SPL_HAUL_IND");

                entity.Property(e => e.OlSplHaulRate)
                    .HasColumnType("NUMBER(22,2)")
                    .HasColumnName("OL_SPL_HAUL_RATE");

                entity.Property(e => e.OlSplitLoad)
                    .HasMaxLength(1)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("OL_SPLIT_LOAD");

                entity.Property(e => e.OlStartDate)
                    .HasColumnType("DATE")
                    .HasColumnName("OL_START_DATE");

                entity.Property(e => e.OlSwb)
                    .HasMaxLength(1)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("OL_SWB");

                entity.Property(e => e.OlTbc)
                    .HasMaxLength(1)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("OL_TBC");

                entity.Property(e => e.OlTime1)
                    .HasMaxLength(5)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("OL_TIME_1");

                entity.Property(e => e.OlTime2)
                    .HasMaxLength(5)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("OL_TIME_2");

                entity.Property(e => e.OlTimeCritical)
                    .HasMaxLength(1)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("OL_TIME_CRITICAL");

                entity.Property(e => e.OlTimeCriticalReason)
                    .HasMaxLength(60)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("OL_TIME_CRITICAL_REASON");

                entity.Property(e => e.OlTonnesPerHour)
                    .HasColumnType("NUMBER(8,2)")
                    .HasColumnName("OL_TONNES_PER_HOUR");

                entity.Property(e => e.OlVehicleRestriction)
                    .HasMaxLength(1)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("OL_VEHICLE_RESTRICTION");

                entity.Property(e => e.OlWhyTbc)
                    .HasMaxLength(60)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("OL_WHY_TBC");
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Order>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => new { e.OrderId })
                    .HasName("ORDERS_PK");

                entity.ToTable("INV_STONE_ORDERS", "LIVE");

                entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.SoIaInvoiceAccount, e.SoDeliveryDate }, "SO_CUST_DATE");

                entity.HasIndex(e => e.SoCustOrderNo, "SO_CUST_ORD");

                entity.HasIndex(e => e.SoDeliveryDate, "SO_DELIVERY_DATE_IDX");

                entity.HasIndex(e => e.OrderId, "SO_INT_ORDER_REF_IDX")
                    .IsUnique();

                entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.OrderId, e.SoIaInvoiceAccount }, "SO_ORD_REF_I_A");

                entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.SoOurOrderNo, e.SoDeliveryDate }, "SO_OUR_ORD");

                entity.HasIndex(e => e.SoOwContract, "SO_OW_CONT");

                entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.SoPostcode1, e.SoPostcode2 }, "SO_POST_CODE");

                entity.HasIndex(e => e.SoRcNumber, "SO_RC");

                entity.HasIndex(e => e.SoToBeLinked, "SO_TO_BE_LINKED");

                entity.Property(e => e.SoAddress1)
                    .HasMaxLength(40)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("SO_ADDRESS_1");

                entity.Property(e => e.SoAddress2)
                    .HasMaxLength(35)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("SO_ADDRESS_2");

                entity.Property(e => e.SoAddress3)
                    .HasMaxLength(35)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("SO_ADDRESS_3");

                entity.Property(e => e.SoAddress4)
                    .HasMaxLength(35)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("SO_ADDRESS_4");

                entity.Property(e => e.SoApproved)
                    .HasMaxLength(1)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("SO_APPROVED");

                entity.Property(e => e.SoApprovedBy)
                    .HasPrecision(4)
                    .HasColumnName("SO_APPROVED_BY");

                entity.Property(e => e.SoAwaitingCreditApproval)
                    .HasMaxLength(1)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("SO_AWAITING_CREDIT_APPROVAL");

                entity.Property(e => e.SoCanTakeToday)
                    .HasMaxLength(1)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("SO_CAN_TAKE_TODAY");

                entity.Property(e => e.SoCancelled)
                    .HasMaxLength(1)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("SO_CANCELLED");

                entity.Property(e => e.SoCancelledContact)
                    .HasMaxLength(30)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("SO_CANCELLED_CONTACT");

                entity.Property(e => e.SoCashCustAcc)
                    .HasMaxLength(100)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("SO_CASH_CUST_ACC");

                entity.Property(e => e.SoCt1CtId)
                    .HasColumnType("NUMBER")
                    .HasColumnName("SO_CT1_CT_ID");

                entity.Property(e => e.SoCt2CtId)
                    .HasColumnType("NUMBER")
                    .HasColumnName("SO_CT2_CT_ID");

                entity.Property(e => e.SoCt3CtId)
                    .HasColumnType("NUMBER")
                    .HasColumnName("SO_CT3_CT_ID");

                entity.Property(e => e.SoCustOrderNo)
                    .HasMaxLength(30)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("SO_CUST_ORDER_NO");

                entity.Property(e => e.SoCustQuoteNo)
                    .HasColumnType("NUMBER(22)")
                    .HasColumnName("SO_CUST_QUOTE_NO");

                entity.Property(e => e.SoDateApproved)
                    .HasColumnType("DATE")
                    .HasColumnName("SO_DATE_APPROVED");

                entity.Property(e => e.SoDateReceived)
                    .HasColumnType("DATE")
                    .HasColumnName("SO_DATE_RECEIVED");

                entity.Property(e => e.SoDelInstructions)
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("SO_DEL_INSTRUCTIONS");

                entity.Property(e => e.SoDeliveryDate)
                    .HasColumnType("DATE")
                    .HasColumnName("SO_DELIVERY_DATE");

                entity.Property(e => e.SoDespNotificationCt1)
                    .HasMaxLength(20)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("SO_DESP_NOTIFICATION_CT1");

                entity.Property(e => e.SoDespNotificationCt2)
                    .HasMaxLength(20)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("SO_DESP_NOTIFICATION_CT2");

                entity.Property(e => e.SoEmpLinkedBy)
                    .HasPrecision(8)
                    .HasColumnName("SO_EMP_LINKED_BY");

                entity.Property(e => e.SoEmpTakenBy)
                    .HasPrecision(6)
                    .HasColumnName("SO_EMP_TAKEN_BY");

                entity.Property(e => e.SoEoShortName)
                    .HasMaxLength(30)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("SO_EO_SHORT_NAME");

                entity.Property(e => e.SoExworks)
                    .HasMaxLength(1)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("SO_EXWORKS");

                entity.Property(e => e.SoFocAuthorisation)
                    .HasMaxLength(20)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("SO_FOC_AUTHORISATION");

                entity.Property(e => e.SoFyPurchInvNo)
                    .HasPrecision(7)
                    .HasColumnName("SO_FY_PURCH_INV_NO");

                entity.Property(e => e.SoIaInvoiceAccount)
                    .HasColumnType("NUMBER(22)")
                    .HasColumnName("SO_IA_INVOICE_ACCOUNT");

                entity.Property(e => e.SoIncomingJourney)
                    .HasMaxLength(1)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("SO_INCOMING_JOURNEY");

                entity.Property(e => e.SoPlacedBy)
truncated for posting

            modelBuilder.HasSequence("WWN_NUMBER_SEQ", "LIVE");

            modelBuilder.HasSequence("ZONE_MAP_SEQUENCE", "LIVE");

            modelBuilder.HasSequence("ZPG_SEQUENCE", "LIVE");

            OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
        }

        partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

As I said, the vast majority of that was generated by scaffolding from the database.  Other than commenting out all but one of the properties and putting them back one by one until I find the offending one, is there a simpler way of debugging this?  Or have I missed a vital pointer in the error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare only date components from DateTime in EF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478215/how-to-compare-only-date-components-from-datetime-in-ef). Refer to Mandeep Janjua's answer.

Comment: @YongShun - thanks for the response, but it doesn't have anything to do with the date comparison. That criteria is only in there to limit the number of records returned, I have millions of orders in my database.  I get the same error if I query for just one order by order number, when the order is one with the data that is failing the comparison.  Even knowing a particular record that fails, I am struggling to find the answer.

Comment: You have 3 `byte` properties, what is the SQL definition of those columns?

Comment: @HenkHolterman - good spot.  These are defined as numbers on the database, changed them to int and it fixed the problem.

Comment: Yes, always check the details. Especially the ones you already know are Ok.

Comment: And apparently, don't trust Entity Framework scaffolding...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @HenkHolterman, scaffolding had defined three columns as byte, when on the database they are number(4).  Changed them to int in my model and we are back in business.