# How to test two dateTimes for being the same date?

Tags: c#, datetime, equality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to compare Dates in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683037/how-to-compare-dates-in-c-sharp)

This code of mine:

```
public static string getLogFileNameForDate(DateTime dt)
{
    if (dt.Equals(DateTime.Now))
```

...fails even when the two dates are the same (date) because dt is assigned a value at startup (e.g. "6/18/2012 15:19:42"), and so the dates are not exactly the same, even though the year, month, and day are the same (value of DateTime.Now may be, say, "6/18/2012 15:30:13").

I know I can test it this way:

```
if ((dt.Year.Equals(DateTime.Now.Year) && (dt.Month.Equals(DateTime.Now.Month) && (dt.Day.Equals(DateTime.Now.Day))
```

...but that seems a bit Jethro*-like

What is the accepted/preferred method (no pun intended)?

- Clampett, not Tull

Comment: dt.Date.CompareTo(DateTime.Now.Date) == 0 should do the trick.

Comment: Oh, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683037/how-to-compare-dates-in-c-sharp

Comment: @dash:  Looks like you need the mythical "Seeing Double" badge for these dupes you keep finding.

Comment: I just keep asking myself: "Surely these can't be original questions" :-) On one hand, it's good the OP get's an answer, but on the other, filling the site with the same answers...

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Try

```
if (dt.Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
```

It will only take the date portion and the timestamp will be 12:00:00

Comment: I assume you can also do `dt.date == DateTime.Today`