# DateTime comparison without time part?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datetime, date-comparison

I wrote this code. But I want to ignore time, I want to compare only day.

```
from s in sayac_okumalari
where s.okuma_tarihi == startDate && s.sayac_id == sayac_id
group s by new { date = new DateTime(((DateTime)s.okuma_tarihi).Year, ((DateTime)s.okuma_tarihi).Month, ((DateTime)s.okuma_tarihi).Day, ((DateTime)s.okuma_tarihi).Hour, 1, 1) } into g
select new
{
     okuma_tarihi = g.Key.date,
     T1 = g.Sum(x => x.toplam_kullanim_T1),
     T2 = g.Sum(x => x.toplam_kullanim_T2),
     T3 = g.Sum(x => x.toplam_kullanim_T3)
};
```

for example:

```
25.02.1987 == 25.02.1987
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare only Date without Time in DateTime types in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683037/how-to-compare-only-date-without-time-in-datetime-types-in-c)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

use `s.okuma_tarihi.Value.Date == startDate.Date`. This should allow you to compare only the Date component.

**Update** From the discussion in comments looks like the user is using NullableType. Hence updated the solution for NullableType.

Comment: 's.okuma_tarihi' does not contain a definition for 'Date'

Comment: Looks like from your code snippet, you need to typecast s.okuma_tarihi to DateTime

Comment: s.okuma_tarihi.Value.Date == startDate.Date is working.If edit your solution I will mark it. Thanks.

Comment: ((DateTime)s.okuma_tarihi).Date use only calling, assigment.

Comment: Updated. But, looks like you are using Nullable type. You may need to ensure that Nullable type has value before performing action.

Comment: This is usefull knowledge for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8):

Use `Date` property of DateTime. For ex,

```
var date= DateTime.Now.Date;
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you could convert `s.okuma_tarihi` to DateTime, I think you could do:

```
var sonuc = from s in sayac_okumalari
        where (DateTime)s.okuma_tarihi.Date == startDate.Date && s.sayac_id == sayac_id
        group s by new { date = new DateTime(((DateTime)s.okuma_tarihi).Year, ((DateTime)s.okuma_tarihi).Month, ((DateTime)s.okuma_tarihi).Day, ((DateTime)s.okuma_tarihi).Hour, 1, 1) } into g
        select new
        {
             okuma_tarihi = g.Key.date,
             T1 = g.Sum(x => x.toplam_kullanim_T1),
             T2 = g.Sum(x => x.toplam_kullanim_T2),
             T3 = g.Sum(x => x.toplam_kullanim_T3)
        };
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Date property on the DateTime Object will be a good a simple solution.

```
string AdmissionDate = "10/15/2017" // mm/dd/yyyy
string DepartureDate = "10/14/2017" // mm/dd/yyyy

if (Convert.ToDateTime(AdmissionDate).Date > Convert.ToDateTime(DepartureDate).Date)
{
    // Validation: Admission Date can not be greater than Departure Date... 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try this...**

```
        try
        {
         DateTime Date1= DateTime.ParseExact(txtBox1.Text,"dd/MM/yyyy",null);
         DateTime Date2 = DateTime.ParseExact(txtBox2.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);

          if (Date1 > Date2) 
          {
           //........
          }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```