# DateCompare in C# like in SQL

Tags: c#, .net, sql, datetime

Is there a method in C# which can compare dates like the SQL `DateDiff` method, including time part argument?

For example I have two dates:

```
DateTime early = "2013.02.01 07:31:15";
DateTime soon = "2013.02.01 23:48:35";

if (Compare(early, soon, DAY) == true)
{
   //I want to be here
}
```

I want to get info that these two objects are equal in year, month and day; the rest is not important to me.

Comment: you could always add `using Microsoft.VisualBasic` and use the VB.NET assembly to do the Compare..

Comment: Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683037/how-to-compare-only-date-without-time-in-datetime-types-in-c

Comment: You ever heard of the `Kiss Method` `Keep It Simple Stupid` here is a simple solution `if (String.Format("{0:ddMMyyyyHHmmss}", early) == String.Format("{0:ddMMyyyyHHmmss}", soon))
{
    // success
}`

Comment: @DJKRAZE: That solution introduces issues with culture, performance, and is *not* as simple as some of the other solutions provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `DateTime.Date`:

```
if(early.Date == soon.Date)
{
}
```

if you want accurancy of hours:

```
if(early.Date == soon.Date && early.Hour == soon.Hour)
{
}
```

But, with this solution you will have "12/03/1857 23:59" != "13/03/1857 00:00". If you want to check their "distance":

```
if(early.Substract(soon).Duration() <= TimeSpan.FromHours(1))
{
}
```

`.Duration()` gets the "absolute" value of the time span (because `early.Substract(soon)` can be "positive" or "negative").

Comment: Yes, you have right :) But if I want to compare DateTime with accuracy to hours?

Comment: @Bruno.cf: `Date` and `Day` are different.

Comment: Bruno.cf you need to look at the `Date` if the months are different then the dates do not equal..so your comment makes `0` sense

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko `I want to get info that these two objects are equal in year, month and day; the rest is not important to me.`. What part of that statement led you to the conclusion this solution is wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [`Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property of your `DateTime`s to just get the date portion.

In your case you could use:

```
if (early.Date == soon.Date)
{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DateTime.Subtract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.subtract.aspx) method to find the difference.

```
System.TimeSpan diff1 = date2.Subtract(date1);
```

**Edit**

If you want to compare for equality you can simply use equality operator ==

```
if(date1 == date2)
{
}
```

Comment: The addition and subtraction operators are overloaded for `DateTime` to return a `TimeSpan`, so `date2 - date1` would be an equivalent alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything wrong with being a little verbose if you want to be explicit about how you're comparing two dates:

```
public static bool YearMonthDayHourDateCompare(DateTime one, DateTime two)
{
    return (one.Year  == two.Year  &&
            one.Month == two.Month &&
            one.Day   == two.Day   &&
            one.Hour  == two.Hour  && 
            ...);
}
```

Name the method in a way that describes your comparison. Better yet, this could be an extension method:

```
public static bool CompareDateAndHour(this DateTime one, DateTime two)
{
    return (one.Date == two.Date &&
            one.Hour == two.Hour && 
            ...);
}
```

Which could be used like:

```
bool datesAreEqual = soon.CompareDateAndHour(two);
```

Comment: +1 for being explicit being a good thing. But forgive me for this... "*nothing wrong with being explicit*" and then you hide it in `MyCustomDateComparer`? ;)

Comment: @J.Steen: Ok, the name of the function stinks -- it was just an example. Perhaps the sample code would be better not wrapped in a function at all. Would you agree?

Comment: I wasn't *too* serious, here, though I'm still always advocating methods and variables having descriptive names. And in this rather lengthy case, a descriptive method name would be better - in my opinion - than having the condition not wrapped at all. =)

Comment: Ouch. Yeah, to the extreme. =) No offence meant, at all.

Comment: @J.Steen: Good point. I should be more careful with sample code on [so].

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if is the same day, you cant use date diff...

Try this code:

```
if(new TimeSpan(early.Ticks).TotalDays() == new TimeSpan(soon.Ticks).TotalDays()){
     // Equal
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var diff=soon-early;
diff.TotalHours or diff.TotalMinutes etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

To compare two dates to an accuracy of hours, use something like this:

```
bool match = (soon - early).TotalHours < *your diff limit*;
```