# Convert DateTime to yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I have certain dates in my DB.

When received in C# Code, they come with values as 2012-02-14T06:02:33, 2014-09-12T03:21:22 and similar.

I want to truncate the time component to 00:00:00, ex: 2012-02-14T00:00:00.

How should I proceed with it?

Tried `DateTime.TryPareExact` with few formats but wasn't able to get the desired results.

My main aim is to just truncate the time part in the dates to 00:00:00.

Experts please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683037/how-to-compare-only-date-without-time-in-datetime-types-in-c

Answer (score 2):

There is no conversion in datetime. If you want to convert a string to datetime, use `DateTime.TryParse()`. If you have a datetime and want a formatted string. You can use a format string:

```
 dateAndTime.ToString("MMMM dd,yyyy");
```

will give you a formatted date string.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the value to a datetime object and can use the .Date property to get the date part only.

```
var dateValue = <<Get Value from DB>>;

var dateValue = dateValue.Date; // To get only the date part
```