# different between date format when get current date only using datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, datetime-format

if my computer datetime format as yy/mm/dd or mm/dd/yyyy or regardless formation

```
Datetime date1 = ... /// assume date1 is date1 < date2 and  date1 < date3 
DateTime date2  = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")) ; 
DateTime  date3  = DateTime.Now.Date;

DateTime.Compare(date1 ,date2);  and DateTime.Compare(date1 ,date3);
```

what would the result ? is it for `date2` and `date3` return 1 when compare `date1` ? 
`DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")` is equal as `DateTime.Now.Date` ?

Comment: what is the `date1`? You code show `...` and define twice of `date2`

Comment: @Alex updated the question.

Comment: @theinarasu - Do you understand that the `DateTime` type does **not** have a format and that it's only when you parse or output it as a `string` that you have a formats? It's the `string` that has a format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why are you doing `DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));`..?

To answer your question, both `date2` and `date3` will become different depending on your computer (or the device that is running this code) localization.

So if `date1` is always earlier you can do `TimeSpan diff = date3 - date1;` which will give you `TimeSpan` object. Then you can `diff.Days` to get the number of days difference.

And yes `date3` will only have date in there. The time will be set to 12:00 midnight. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx).

[TimeSpan.Days](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.days(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: is that wrong approach ? please correct me if am wrong , the main purpose i do so to get current date only without time , DateTime.Now.date this will return time 12.00pm

Comment: Parsing datetime now to string and back is very wrong. i18n will kill you there.

Comment: thank you for point it out ...  but DateTime.now.Date was return with time as 12.00 AM .. it's cause any problem when Datetime.compare because the date1 value im passing in only with date without time

Comment: @theinarasu Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683037/how-to-compare-only-date-without-time-in-datetime-types-in-c)

Comment: All DateTime object has time in there. If no time is passed in it will default to 12.00AM / 00:00

Comment: @Bob Thank you bro! much appreciate for the help

Answer (score 0):

If you want only datewithout time, then you can try
  string x = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(); 
Result will be x = "09-09-2016"