# DatePart method in Entity Framework Core 3.0

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

How do I use methods such as **DatePart** or **TruncateTime**, etc. in Entity Framework Core 3.0? In Entity Framework 6.3.0 it was possible to call for example

> DbFunctions.TruncateTime

but now there is no such method.
I found that something like this can be done with the code shown below, but I didn't manage to get it working since the constructor of the SqlFragmentExpression is internal:

```
public int? DatePart(string datePartArg, DateTime? date) => throw new Exception();

public void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    var methodInfo = typeof(DbContext).GetRuntimeMethod(nameof(DatePart), new[] { typeof(string), typeof(DateTime) });
    modelBuilder
        .HasDbFunction(methodInfo)
        .HasTranslation(args => new SqlFunctionExpression(nameof(DatePart), typeof(int?), new[]
                {
                        new SqlFragmentExpression(args.ToArray()[0].ToString()),
                        args.ToArray()[1]
                }));
}
```

Here is a simple LINQ query I'm trying to get working:

```
context.Books.Any(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.date) == data.Date);
```

Is there some other way to accomplish that, or is there at least someone working on adding these features?

---

### Edit 1

To clarify my problem - I need to group the rows by the result of DatePart afterward.

Comment: Are _data.Date_ and _Books.date_ of different types? And the _date_ column of the _Book_ table in the database is not of type _DATE_? Would it help to set the SQL data type of the column on the model property to "DATE"?. It's not obvious to me why the _TruncateTime()_ is needed here.

Comment: See Comments and answers in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40758784/dbfunctions-truncatetime-linq-equivalent-in-ef-core

Answer (score 1):

I learned quite some things from that question. The following linq statement should work for you:

`context.Books.Any(x => x.date.Date == data.Date);`

But some functions can be accessed from EF core. E.G.:

```
var dbf = EF.Functions;
_DB.Books.Any(x => EF.Functions.Contains(x.Name, "Galaxy"));
```

There is also a *scalar function mapping* feature since EF core 2.0 that allows to map Linq functions to Scalar Database functions. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. Sorry, my question might be a little bit unclear, so I'm editing it. The shown code was just a small query to test this, but what I really need is to user GroupBy on the DatePart.