# Remove time from Date Time in Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my web application, I want to show data only between 2 days ago that records from ''DateTime.Today''.

to get the date of 2 days ago date I tried

`DateTime twoDaysAgo = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2);`

And then in the query

```
 smcNews = (from n in db.NewsShare 
            join e in db.CreateEmployee on n.Created_By equals e.Id join d in db.CreateDepartment on e.DepId equals d.Id 
            where n.CreatedDate > twoDaysAgo && n.CreatedDate <= DateTime.Today 
            select new NewsShareViewModel {
              Id = n.Id,
              UserName = e.EmpName,
              Department = d.Department,
              Message = n.Comment,
              UserId = n.Created_By,
              CreatedDate = n.CreatedDate.ToString()
              }).ToList();
```

it won't return data. I checked the value of `twoDaysAgo` and it's like `{12/29/2021 12:00:00 AM}`

the data in the `CreatedDate` is `2021-12-31 13:43:19.957`

So I there any way to get this query right by removing the time from the date or something ?

Comment: Does `n.CreatedDate.Date` not work?

Comment: @Llama nope. When it add then I got this error ``The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.``

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: @phuzi Yes. The code is within the controller

Comment: Please remember to mention if you're using LINQ to SQL or EF :) You certainly wouldn't get an error there if you were just using the code to query a `List<something>`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`n.CreatedDate <= DateTime.Today` is effectively `n.CreatedDate <= 2021-12-31 00:00:00`.

> the data in the CreatedDate is 2021-12-31 13:43:19.957

A datetime of `2021-12-31 13:43:19.957` is not "less than or equal to" `2021-12-31 00:00:00`

Remove the `&& n.CreatedDate <= DateTime.Today`  condition - it's doing nothing for you (other than excluding any data you created today), assuming records cannot be created in the future, and assuming you want all records created since midnight two days ago

> I there any way to get this query right by removing the time from the date or something ?

Avoid doing this wherever possible; aim to always use a range of fixed constant values from/to when you're searching data in a range.

Do not manipulate table data in a Where clause, unless you want to create queries that cannot use indexes (and become a performance issue as a result)

Answer (score 0):

A datetime always includes a time. You cannot avoid this.

If your start date is the 29th, that means your `Today` value is the 31st at midnight. `2021-12-31 13:43:19.957` is after midnight, so it falls out of the range you specified.

Instead, use the next day (the 1st at midnight) as the upper boundary.

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2); //29th
DateTime end = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);    //1st
```

And then filter using:

```
where n.CreatedDate >= start && n.CreatedDate < end
```

Note the use of `>=` and `<`. This makes sure to include everything from the 29th, 30th and 31st; but nothing from the 1st.

Comment: I tried this, but still it won't get the data. The date time format within the Create date is ``2021-12-31 13:43:19.957`` and the DateTime format in the Start is ``12/29/2021 12:00:00 AM`` the format didn't match. Will it gonna be problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use `n.CreatedDate.Date` with EF. I'm guessing that you're using an EF version for .Net Framework as [DateTime.Date is supported in EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40760245/592958)

Instead you should use [`DbFunctions.TruncateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.truncatetime?view=entity-framework-6.2.0).

```
DbFunctions.TruncateTime(n.CreatedDate) >= twoDaysAgo &&
DbFunctions.TruncateTime(n.CreatedDate) <= DateTime.Today
```

**Update - Don't do it this way - it'll be relatively slow compared to correctly ranging your query**

Comment: No, don't manipulate table data to satisfy conditions that can be satisfied just as easily with more sensibly specified ranges

Comment: @phuzi its ef version for net framework 4.7.

Comment: @CaiusJard Good point, It will be more performant that way.