# Entity Framework Core 6 - Date Comparision

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I need to create a query to find records between a date range. I need to truncate the time for comparison. I came across a few threads suggesting to truncate time using `DbFunctions.TruncateTime` when comparing the dates.

I cannot find `DbFunctions` class in EntityFrameworkCore 6.0. How do I truncate time and compare the DateTime columns?

Edit: Excerpt from my query handler

```
IQueryable<TestReportItem> query = _context.TestReportItems;
DateTime requestDateStart = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(request.TestDateStart).LocalDateTime;
DateTime requestDateEnd = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(request.TestDateEnd).LocalDateTime;

if (request.FacilityId != 0)
{
    query = query.Where(e => e.FacilityId == request.FacilityId);
}

if (request.TestDateStart != 0 && request.TestDateEnd != 0)
{
    query.Where(e => e.TestDate.Date >= requestDateStart
        && e.TestDate.Date <= requestDateEnd);
}

var count = query.Count();

return count;
```

The request will be for a date range (dates converted into `UnixTimeMilliseconds`). I am using SqLite database.

Comment: It would be great if you could share the code what you are up to now, so that it can be reproduce easily to assist you quickly.

Comment: What format you need the time ?

Comment: @DarkkL The DB column holds full DateTime values like `2022-01-02 09:50:22`. I need to truncate the time and compare. For example, I need to select all the records with dates equal to `2022-01-02`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DbFunctions.TruncateTime LINQ equivalent in EF CORE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40758784/dbfunctions-truncatetime-linq-equivalent-in-ef-core)

Comment: That said, if you compare dates by `>=` and `<=` there's no need to truncate them first. Also, if you run your code you should find out that `e.TestDate.Date` works.

Comment: You can try like this way, first define your rage `DateTime stratDate = new DateTime(2021, 6, 1);
            DateTime endDate = DateTime.Now;` then  `var results = _context.UserLogs.Where(t => t.TestDate.Date >= stratDate && t.TestDate.Date <= endDate);`

Comment: @GertArnold Yes. I was able to get the correct results.. Thank you.